# Sorting based on a field and add a specific record on top of the results

Tags: mongodb, sorting, mongodb-query

I have the below set of user records, I need the results in such a way that the logged-in user (`ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a")` and `status: Active`) should come first, followed by the users with `status: Pending` and finally rest of the `status: Active` users.

How do I achieve this using MongoDB query?

```
[
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("654b7348e704b8abba8af17e"),
    "name": "",
    "email" : "",
    "status" : "Active"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("654b6c662f38d9e087086193"),
    "name": "",
    "email" : "",
    "status" : "Pending"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("654b7fbae8392eddee2d1a31"),
    "name": "",
    "email" : "",
    "status" : "Pending"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a"),
    "name": "",
    "email" : "",
    "status" : "Active"
  },
  {
    "_id" : ObjectId("653269653bc13f1b96c6c37d"),
    "name": "",
    "email" : "",
    "status" : "Active"
  }
]
```

Comment: **1.** Format your sample data correctly. You're missing commas on most of the lines. **2.** Provide example values for objectIDs. You say you want ObjectID='something' & status='Active' first, then all Pending and then all remaining Active. So add IDs for those users so that you know which one is correct. **3.** Show what you have tried so far (code) and be specific about which part is giving you trouble. Read: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have updated the question, For me sort by status with order find({}).sort({"status":-1} ) works to make status : Pending records first. But adding the logged in user on top in the response  is the difficult part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

1. `$facet` - Allow to run multiple pipelines in a single query. Each pipeline contains the filter criteria that return different datasets.
2. `$project` - Decorate the output document. Combine the datasets from the previous stage into a single array.
3. `$unwind` - Deconstruct the `users` array.
4. `$replaceWith` - Replace the input document with `users` document.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $facet: {
      loginUsers: [
        {
          $match: {
            _id: ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a"),
            status: "Active"
          }
        }
      ],
      pendingUsers: [
        {
          $match: {
            status: "Pending"
          }
        }
      ],
      activeUsers: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$status",
                    "Active"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $ne: [
                    "$_id",
                    ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a")
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      users: {
        $concatArrays: [
          "$loginUsers",
          "$pendingUsers",
          "$activeUsers"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$users"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$users"
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 1 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/kZXoEdpQ3cT)

---

**Solution 2:**

1. `$set` - Add `rank` field to assign the value based on criteria via `$switch`.
2. `$match` - Remove the document with `rank: -1` in case there is the document with the status other than "Pending" and "Active".
3. `$sort` - Sort by the `rank` field ascending.
4. `$unset` - Remove the `rank` field.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      rank: {
        $switch: {
          branches: [
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$_id",
                      ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a")
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$status",
                      "Active"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: 0
            },
            {
              case: {
                $eq: [
                  "$status",
                  "Pending"
                ]
              },
              then: 1
            },
            {
              case: {
                $and: [
                  {
                    $ne: [
                      "$_id",
                      ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a")
                    ]
                  },
                  {
                    $eq: [
                      "$status",
                      "Active"
                    ]
                  }
                ]
              },
              then: 2
            }
          ],
          default: -1
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      rank: {
        $ne: -1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      rank: 1
    }
  },
  {
    $unset: "rank"
  }
])
```

[Demo Solution 2 @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/4tbNj4ryQEk)

Comment: I prefer this solution over mine. Since `switch` can be easily extended for multiple other conditions and then there are fewer extra _added_ fields to sort by or remove at the end. +1

Answer (score 1):

Add "sorting key" fields to your records, one for the exact match and one for the account status. Since 0 < 1, set those field values accordingly. These fields are only in the pipeline/results, they are not added to your actual records.

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $addFields: {
        id_you_are_looking_for: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: ["$_id", ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a")] },
            then: 0,  // exact match gets lowest value
            else: 1,
          },
        },
        acc_status_sort: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: ["$status", "Pending"] },
            then: 0,  // status pending gets lowest value
            else: 1,
          },
        },
      },
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        id_you_are_looking_for: 1,  // first, ascending order sort on exact match
        acc_status_sort: 1,  // then, ascending order sort on status
      },
    },
    // remove the extra fields added
    // comment out this part to see the sorting fields in results
    {
      $project: {
        id_you_are_looking_for: 0,
        acc_status_sort: 0,
      },
    },
  ]
)
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1w_uK1pnpDR), with the sort key fields present for clarity.

As an alternative, you could also add the non-exact matches as nested conditions of `else` in the first `$cond` to use values `1` & `2` for account status and then sort on only one field.

```js
db.collection.aggregate(
  [
    {
      $addFields: {
        acc_status_sort: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $eq: ["$_id", ObjectId("653222c20489664953bbaf1a")] },
            then: 0, // exact match gets lowest value
            else: {
              $cond: {
                if: { $eq: ["$status", "Pending"] },
                then: 1,  // status pending gets the next value
                else: 2,  // all others give the highest value
              },
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
    { $sort: { acc_status_sort: 1 } },
    { $unset: "acc_status_sort" },  // remove the extra fields added
  ]
)
```

[Mongo Playground for nested `$cond`](https://mongoplayground.net/p/bUU2rEuEBMg).